# Poor performance of QNetworkAccessManages::get()

Tags: c++, performance, qt, networking

QNetwotkAccessManages::get() function lasts for a while (about 7-10 seconds) getting a page that opens in a moment in any browser.

Actually, I try to get http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=myrequest.

Here's the simplified code:

```
void ApiGoogleSearch::getSuggestions()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            SLOT(getSuggestionsFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search"
             "?client=chrome&q=myrequest");
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    qDebug() << "get() started";
}

void ApiGoogleSearch::getSuggestionsFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "ApiGoogleSearch::getSuggestionsFinished() started";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Google somewhy returns that page for my app in a long time. Any other webpage loads quite quick.